# Meteor mobile application STOPS working over 2G and 3G networks

Tags: meteor

I am working with a Meteor mobile application with [Cordova and PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap).

My app is working fine over a Wi-Fi connection. But whenever I use it on mobile networks, 2G or 3G, it stops working. `Meteor.status()` returns `disconnected` all time on mobile cellular  networks.

What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could occur if you have a bad connection. The Meteor in the device's browser can't really tell what network it's on. It just uses whatever it gets.

As soon as it can get a connection back it should reconnect. Keep in mind with 2G (EDGE/GPRS) connections you might have to wait a bit longer for the HTML/JavaScript to connect to the DDP server as all the client HTML/JavaScript data needs to be downloaded first. This can take quite a while.

The other thing is to ensure your (3G) connection isn't over some kind of proxy, especially if you're hosting the application yourself on an unusual port number (websockets usually fall back to long polling, though).

Comment: i am not working with mobile browser . if i run my app on mobile browser there is no issue with 2G,3G or wifi . it works on all . i build APK using cordova phoneGap. and APK not working in 2G and 3G only.. i am not using any proxy for 3G.